# --pythonpath option not working with Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, pageobjects

I am writing a custom Page Object library for Robot Framework like this one: [robotframework-pageobjectlibrary](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary)

My page custom keywords (page objects) are in a separate folder and when I run my `Robot Framework` tests, I give their path with the `--pythonpath` option like this: `robot --pythonpath ../resources/pageobjects lib-test/test.robot`.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
CustomPageObjectLibrary
|--__init__.py
|--keywords.py
|--locatormap.py
|--pageobject.py
Resources
|--pageobjects
   |__CountryPage.py
Tests
|--lib-test
   |__test.robot
```

The contents of the CustomPageObjectLibrary are currently the same as in the linked repo except that I use the `AppiumLibrary` instead of the `SeleniumLibrary`.

CountryPage.py

```
from CustomPageObjectLibrary import PageObject

class CountryPage(PageObject):
  PAGE_TITLE = "Country"

  _locators = {
    'germany': 'countryGermany',
  }

# def __init__(self):
#     super(PageObject, self).__init__()

  def open_app(self):
    self.appiumlib.open_application('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', platformName='Android', deviceName='...', appPackage='...', appActivity='.MainActivity', uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout=50000)


  def choose_country(self, country):
    # Convert country to lovercase
    country = str(country).lower()
```

self.appiumlib.wait_until_element_is_visible(locator=self.locator.germany)
        self.appiumlib.click_element(locator=self.locator.germany)

My test:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables       ../../resources/pageobjects/config.py
Library         CustomPageObjectLibrary
Library         AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Navigate To Not Connected Screen
Open App
Choose country      germany
```

I run this with the following command: `robot --pythonpath ../resources/pageobjects lib-test/test.robot`

The error what I get: `No keyword with name 'Open App' found.`

What could be the problem with this?

Comment: The error you mention has nothing to do with pythonpath. Robot is clearly finding your `CustomAppiumLibrary` library, but it's not finding any keywords in it. Without seeing a simplified version of the library, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: It's not finding the keywords, because they're not there. My keywords are inside the folder what I give as an option with `--pythonpath`. My folder structure is the same as in your library @BryanOakley

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Not directly related to page objects, tag can be removed.

Comment: maybe jus export the PYTHONPATH? `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/root/dir`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the page object library to work, you must first import `PageObjectLibrary` in your test. Then, you must request that a page object library be loaded before you can use the keywords in that library.

Since your `Open App` keyword is in a page object library, you must first call `go to page  CountryPage` or `the current page should be  CountryPage`. Calling either of those keywords will cause your library to be loaded, which then makes the keywords available.

Comment: I understand, but in your library demo, you have a `resources` folder with two classes in it (`LoginPage` and `HomePage`) and in the tutorial you run it with this command: `robot --outputdir results --pythonpath resources demo/tests`. So you are giving an entire folder and in your robot file you are importing the `PageObjectLibrary` as it is. I followed the same principle, but yours is working, mine is not. How is that possible?

Comment: How can I achieve so that I will not need to include every page separately because I will have a lot?

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert: I apologize. I misunderstood your question. I've revised my answer.

Comment: Can I load all of the page objects from python code, what do you say? I don't want to call explicitly `Go to page` or something else all the time.

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert If you don't want to have to load them in via a keyword, why do you need page objects at all? Why not just create a standard keyword library?

Comment: I want to separate the keywords in classes, but I don't want to call them explicitly. It's a mobile application, the page objects are for separation only. @BryanOakley what do you suggest?